# Calling methods on objects inside a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Why can't you access the object property with dot notation inside a loop?

```
var rockSpearguns = {
  Sharpshooter: {barbs: 2, weight: 10, heft: "overhand"},
  Pokepistol: {barbs: 4, weight: 8, heft: "shoulder"}
};
function listGuns(guns) {
  for ( var gun in guns ) {
    console.log("Behold! " + gun + ", with "  + gun.heft + " heft!");
  }
}
listGuns(rockSpearguns);
```

This produces this output:

> Behold! Sharpshooter, with undefined heft!
>   Behold! Pokepistol, with undefined heft!

But, if I change `gun.heft` to `guns[gun].heft`, I get the correct output.

> Behold! Sharpshooter, with overhand heft!
>   Behold! Pokepistol, with shoulder heft!

It seems that *I can* get the name of the gun inside the loop, but *I can't* call a method on it to get the heft. Why?

In, say Ruby, inside a loop, the the current item at index is usually an object. No so here?

Comment: You're trying to get the property of string, not the object it maps to.

Comment: And the answer is: read the friggin manual. That's how JavaScript works.

Comment: Check out this question for information about proper way to get the for-each loop working in js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript

Comment: Javascript is not Ruby or PHP. `for-in` is not like PHP `foreach`.

Comment: @vbo: Except that question is about arrays rather than objects.

Comment: You topic description is weird 'Calling methods on objects' ?

Comment: @ram In addition to not knowing how `for-in` works, he also doesn't know the difference between calling methods and accessing properties.

Comment: @ Jumbalaya: *"It seems that I can get the name of the gun inside the loop, but I can't call a method on it to get the heft. Why?"* What makes you say that? Nothing in your code is trying to call a method on the gun objects. If it were, `guns[gun].methodName();` would work, for the same reason `guns[gun].heft` works.

Comment: @Barmar: I can agree with not knowing how accessing element in 'for-in ' works but definitely can't tolerate with calling methods with the kind of object he described. :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder indeed, so it's not an answer but comment. I am just suggesting Jumbalaya to learn more about looping in javascript in general.

Comment: @everyone I'm just learning JavaScript. Please take it easy.

Comment: @ram your description of a question title is weird. "Topic description?"

Answer (score 2):

> But, if I change `gun.heft` to `guns[gun].heft`, I get the correct output.
>
> ...
>
> It seems that I *can* get the name of the gun inside the loop, but I *can't* call a method on it to get the heft. Why?

There's no code in your question trying to use a method on the objects. If there were, it would work, for the same reason that `guns[gun].heft` works:

```
// The function we'll make a method
function getGunHeft() {
    return this.heft;
}

// Create the objects with that function on them as a method
var rockSpearguns = {
  Sharpshooter: {barbs: 2, weight: 10, heft: "overhand", getHeft: getGunHeft},
  Pokepistol: {barbs: 4, weight: 8, heft: "shoulder", getHeft: getGunHeft}
};

// Use the method
function listGuns(guns) {
  for ( var gun in guns ) {
    console.log("Behold! " + gun + ", with "  + guns[gun].getHeft(); + " heft!");
  }
}
listGuns(rockSpearguns);
```

"Methods" in JavaScript are just functions attached to object properties (either directly, as above, or through the object's underlying "prototype" object). So if you can access an object property, you can call the function it refers to.

When you call a function as part of the same expression where you get the function from an object property, the JavaScript engine sets `this` to refer to the object during the call to the function. That's why I used `this.heft` above to access the `heft` property of the gun.

More in this article on my blog: [*Mythical Methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)

Answer (score 1):

When you're navigating through an object with a for-each loop, you have to use `guns[gun]` to access said object, presuming you're object is `guns` and you're looping through to find `gun`.

Answer (score 1):

`gun` here would be the index of your loop. Try:

```
function listGuns(guns) {
  for ( var gun in guns ) {
    console.log("Behold! " + gun + ", with "  + guns[gun].heft + " heft!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're relating the loop to Ruby, I'll show the comparison:

JS:

```
for (gun in guns)
```

is analogous to Ruby:

```
guns.keys.each do |gun|
```

In both cases, `gun` is set to the property *name*, not the property *value*. To get the corresponding value, you have to access `guns[gun]` in both languages.

In Ruby you would probably write the loop as:

```
guns.each do |gunname, gun|
```

so that you can access properties of the `gun` object directly. Javascript doesn't have this operation built in, but it's simply to write a function that does it.

Answer (score 1):

`gun.heft` doesn't work inside `for-in` loop since `gun` is local variable inside `for-in` loop which is of `string` type and placeholder for the key of Object being iterated.

```
var guns = {
  Sharpshooter: {barbs: 2, weight: 10, heft: "overhand"},
  Pokepistol: {barbs: 4, weight: 8, heft: "shoulder"}
};
for(var gun in guns){ 
  console.log(typeof(gun)) 
}

# print string two times
```

Hence, you need to use `guns[gun]` to access particular gun's value.
And, `guns[gun].heft` would work since value at `guns[gun]` is an object.

Hope it help you to understand more.
[Click Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to know more on `for-in` loop.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here still in 2022 you could also do this:

```
function listGuns(guns) {
  for (let [gun, value] of Object.entries(guns)) {
    console.log("Behold! " + gun + ", with " + value.heft + " heft!");
  }
}
```

see source on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#see_also)